# Problem after an update to TeX Live 2020 from 2018

Tags: tikz-pgf, xparse, texlive-2020

The following command works fine with a TeX Live 2018, but after I have updated to TeX Live 2020, I have this error. I can't find what is the problem :

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \OT1\j 
l.85     <Prix >{,,5,7.5}[$\times\dots$]
                                        
?
```

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
    % hauteur des lignes
    BLS/.store in=\BLS,
    BLS=1.1*\baselineskip,
    % largeur étiquette
    TDP etq width/.store in=\TDPew,
    TDP etq width=3em,
    % largeur cases
    TDP case width/.store in=\TDPcw,
    TDP case width=3em,
    }

    \tikzset{%
        % style général des cases
        TDPnode/.style={outer sep=0pt,inner sep=1pt,
            minimum height=\BLS,draw,text depth=2pt},
        % style des étiquettes de ligne
        TDPetq/.style={TDPnode,anchor=north east,fill=gray,
            minimum width=\TDPew + 9pt,align=left,
            text width=\TDPew},
        % style des cases
        TDPcas/.style={TDPnode,anchor=west,minimum width=\TDPcw},
        % style de la flèche
        TDPfle/.style={>=stealth,semithick}
    }


\NewDocumentCommand{\TDP}
    {
    o       % fleche gauche
    d<>     % etq 
    m       % liste 1ere ligne separateur "," 
    d<>     % etq ;
    m       % liste 2sde ligne separateur ","
    o       % fleche droite
    }
    {%
    
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
    % On traite l'etiquette
    \node[TDPetq] (A0) at (0,\BLS)  {\strut#2} ; }{
    \coordinate (A0) at (0,\BLS) ;}
    
    % traite la liste
    \foreach \x [count=\i from 0, count=\j from 1] in {#3} {%
        \node[TDPcas] (A\j) at (A\i.east) {\strut\x} ;
        }
    \node[TDPcas,draw=none] (AF) at (A\j.west) {} ;
    
    \IfValueTF{#4}{%
    % On traite l'etiquette
    \node[TDPetq] (B0) at (0,0) {\strut#4} ;}{
    \coordinate (B0) at (0,0) ;}

    % traite la liste
    \foreach \x [count=\i from 0, count=\j from 1] in {#5} {%
        \node[TDPcas] (B\j) at (B\i.east) {\strut\x} ;
        }
    \node[TDPcas,draw=none] (BF) at (B\j.west) {} ;

    \IfValueTF{#1}{% fleche de gauche
        \draw[TDPfle,<-] ([xshift=-2pt]A0.west)
        arc (90:270:{.6*\BLS} and 0.5*\BLS)
        node[midway,left=-2pt] {#1};
    }{3}

    \IfValueTF{#6}{% fleche de droite
        \draw[TDPfle,->] ([xshift=2pt]AF.east)
        arc (90:-90:{.6*\BLS} and 0.5*\BLS)
        node[midway,right=-2pt] {#6};
    }{}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    TDP etq width=2cm,baseline={(0,0)},
    every node/.style={text depth=2pt}]
    
    \TDP[$\dots\times$]<Masse (kg)>{0.5,1,2,}%
    <Prix >{,,5,7.5}[$\times\dots$]
        
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have two `\node`s that use a counter `\j` outside of the `\foreach` loop.  In TL 2018 it worked because `\foreach` would define `\j` globally, but now it restores `\j` to its old meaning (dotless j) after the loop ends.  Do you need those `\node`s outside the `\foreach`?

Comment: Yes. '\j' is used to name the nodes ans to refer to them eventually later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an [intentional change](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/702) in Ti*k*Z because otherwise you'd usually lose the dotless i and j characters because `\i` and `\j` are often used as loop variables in `\foreach`.

To use the last item in the loop after the loop ends you can add `\xdef\lastj{\j}` inside the `\foreach`, then outside use `\lastj` instead.

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
    % hauteur des lignes
    BLS/.store in=\BLS,
    BLS=1.1*\baselineskip,
    % largeur étiquette
    TDP etq width/.store in=\TDPew,
    TDP etq width=3em,
    % largeur cases
    TDP case width/.store in=\TDPcw,
    TDP case width=3em,
    }

    \tikzset{%
        % style général des cases
        TDPnode/.style={outer sep=0pt,inner sep=1pt,
            minimum height=\BLS,draw,text depth=2pt},
        % style des étiquettes de ligne
        TDPetq/.style={TDPnode,anchor=north east,fill=gray,
            minimum width=\TDPew + 9pt,align=left,
            text width=\TDPew},
        % style des cases
        TDPcas/.style={TDPnode,anchor=west,minimum width=\TDPcw},
        % style de la flèche
        TDPfle/.style={>=stealth,semithick}
    }


\NewDocumentCommand{\TDP}
    {
    o       % fleche gauche
    d<>     % etq 
    m       % liste 1ere ligne separateur "," 
    d<>     % etq ;
    m       % liste 2sde ligne separateur ","
    o       % fleche droite
    }
    {%
    
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
    % On traite l'etiquette
    \node[TDPetq] (A0) at (0,\BLS)  {\strut#2} ; }{
    \coordinate (A0) at (0,\BLS) ;}
    
    % traite la liste
    \foreach \x [count=\i from 0, count=\j from 1] in {#3} {%
        \node[TDPcas] (A\j) at (A\i.east) {\strut\x} ;
        \xdef\lastj{\j} % define here
        }
    \node[TDPcas,draw=none] (AF) at (A\lastj.west) {} ; % use \lastj outside
    
    \IfValueTF{#4}{%
    % On traite l'etiquette
    \node[TDPetq] (B0) at (0,0) {\strut#4} ;}{
    \coordinate (B0) at (0,0) ;}

    % traite la liste
    \foreach \x [count=\i from 0, count=\j from 1] in {#5} {%
        \node[TDPcas] (B\j) at (B\i.east) {\strut\x} ;
        \xdef\lastj{\j} % define here
        }
    \node[TDPcas,draw=none] (BF) at (B\lastj.west) {} ; % use \lastj outside

    \IfValueTF{#1}{% fleche de gauche
        \draw[TDPfle,<-] ([xshift=-2pt]A0.west)
        arc (90:270:{.6*\BLS} and 0.5*\BLS)
        node[midway,left=-2pt] {#1};
    }{3}

    \IfValueTF{#6}{% fleche de droite
        \draw[TDPfle,->] ([xshift=2pt]AF.east)
        arc (90:-90:{.6*\BLS} and 0.5*\BLS)
        node[midway,right=-2pt] {#6};
    }{}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    TDP etq width=2cm,baseline={(0,0)},
    every node/.style={text depth=2pt}]
    
    \TDP[$\dots\times$]<Masse (kg)>{0.5,1,2,}%
    <Prix >{,,5,7.5}[$\times\dots$]
        
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570991) explains one of the changes of pgf, which caused the problem. However, there is also another change which allows you to smuggle the counts out of the group: `\pgfutil@pushmacro` and `\pgfutil@popmacro`. While I am not sure if I wanted to use `\i` and `\j` for the counters, you can use the above-mentioned macros to smuggle the macros out of the `foreach` loop. These tricks can be used more generally to export anything that you need out of the local group that is generated by `\foreach`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\pgfpush[1]{\pgfutil@pushmacro#1}
\newcommand\pgfpop[1]{\pgfutil@popmacro#1}
\makeatother

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
    % hauteur des lignes
    BLS/.store in=\BLS,
    BLS=1.1*\baselineskip,
    % largeur etiquette
    TDP etq width/.store in=\TDPew,
    TDP etq width=3em,
    % largeur cases
    TDP case width/.store in=\TDPcw,
    TDP case width=3em,
    }

    \tikzset{%
        % style general des cases
        TDPnode/.style={outer sep=0pt,inner sep=1pt,
            minimum height=\BLS,draw,text depth=2pt},
        % style des etiquettes de ligne
        TDPetq/.style={TDPnode,anchor=north east,fill=gray,
            minimum width=\TDPew + 9pt,align=left,
            text width=\TDPew},
        % style des cases
        TDPcas/.style={TDPnode,anchor=west,minimum width=\TDPcw},
        % style de la fleche
        TDPfle/.style={>=stealth,semithick}
    }


\NewDocumentCommand{\TDP}%
    {
    o       % fleche gauche
    d<>     % etq 
    m       % liste 1ere ligne separateur "," 
    d<>     % etq ;
    m       % liste 2sde ligne separateur ","
    o       % fleche droite
    }
    {%
    %
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
    % On traite l'etiquette
    \node[TDPetq] (A0) at (0,\BLS)  {\strut#2} ; }{
    \coordinate (A0) at (0,\BLS) ;}
%     %
%     % traite la liste
    \foreach \x [count=\i from 0, count=\j from 1] in {#3} {%
        \node[TDPcas] (A\j) at (A\i.east) {\strut\x} ;
        \pgfpush\j
        }
    \pgfpop\j   
    \node[TDPcas,draw=none] (AF) at (A\j.west) {} ;
%   %   
    \IfValueTF{#4}{%
    % On traite l'etiquette
    \node[TDPetq] (B0) at (0,0) {\strut#4} ;}{
    \coordinate (B0) at (0,0) ;}
    % traite la liste
    \foreach \x [count=\i from 0, count=\j from 1] in {#5} {%
        \node[TDPcas] (B\j) at (B\i.east) {\strut\x} ;
        \pgfpush\j
        }
    \pgfpop\j       
    \node[TDPcas,draw=none] (BF) at (B\j.west) {} ;
    \IfValueTF{#1}{% fleche de gauche
        \draw[TDPfle,<-] ([xshift=-2pt]A0.west)
        arc (90:270:{.6*\BLS} and 0.5*\BLS)
        node[midway,left=-2pt] {#1};
    }{3}
    \IfValueTF{#6}{% fleche de droite
        \draw[TDPfle,->] ([xshift=2pt]AF.east)
        arc (90:-90:{.6*\BLS} and 0.5*\BLS)
        node[midway,right=-2pt] {#6};
    }{}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    TDP etq width=2cm,baseline={(0,0)},
    every node/.style={text depth=2pt}]
    
    \TDP[$\dots\times$]<Masse (kg)>{0.5,1,2,}%
    <Prix >{,,5,7.5}[$\times\dots$]      
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]